# Routing problems with AngularJS and Symfony

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony

I'm trying to work with symfony2 and AngularJs together, but I cant,

1. I've conflicts with the rounting
2. Angular does not  recognize the Angular symbols in twig templates.

This is my `app.js` that is in `AppBundle/Resoures/public/js/app.js`

```js
var app = angular.module('uifi',[]);

app.config(['$stateProvider','$interpolateProvider',
  function($stateProvider,$interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');

    $stateProvider.state('grupos', {
        url: '/grupos',
        templateUrl: Routing.generate('app_grupos_index'),
        controller : 'GruposController'
    });
}]);
```

This is my page `index.html.twig` that has a dummy content

```xhtml
<html ng-app="uifi">

<body>

    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/angular.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/controllers/GrupoController.js') }}"></script>

    <div ng-controller="GruposController">
        [[title]]
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my `Angular controller` to setup the `title` variable

```js
app.controller('GruposController',['$scope',
  function($scope){
      $scope.title ='Research groups';
  }
]);
```

Then my controller in `symfony` to handle the `app_grupos_index`

```php
class GruposController extends Controller{

  /**
   * @Route(name="app_list_grupos",options={"expose"=true})
   */
  public function getListGrupos(){
    $grupos = $this->get('uifi.integrantes.grupos')->getGrupos();
    return new JsonResponse( array('grupos'=> $grupos) );
  }

  /**
   * @Route(name="app_grupos_index",options={"expose"=true})
   */
  public function indexAction(){
    return  $this->render('AppBundle:Grupos:index.html.twig');
  }
}
```

Note that I'm using `FOSJsRoutingBundle` to expose the symfony routes to `Javascript`

**Problems:**

1. If I  go to the route `http://localhost:8000/grupos` in the browser I get the following  `Symfony error`:

   `No route found for "GET /grupos"`

   This problem make me think in that Angular is not working with the routing
2. If I modify the `Symfony controller` to handle the route `/grupos` like this:

```php
  /**
   * @Route("/grupos",name="app_grupos_index",options={"expose"=true})
   */
  public function indexAction(){
    return  $this->render('AppBundle:Grupos:index.html.twig');
  }
```

I get my page with the explicit `[[title]]` string and  the following `Angular error`:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector
/modulerr?p0=uifi&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F
%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.14%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngRoute%26p1....
```

So, I'm wondering what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I go to the `http://localhost:8000/#grupos` I have a route that handle everything that go to `http://localhost:8000/`  to redirecting to `http://localhost:8000/login` then  I'm in the `http://localhost:8000/login` :/

Comment: Well, first you should probably include the ui-router JS file and add `'ui.router'` to your module's dependencies

Answer (score 0):

There are lot more things you'll need to consider when integrating symfony with angular.

1. Routing should completely handled in client side. Symfony should only render the initial index route. There is no point of having angular here if you'd use server side rendering.
2. Backend should act as an API provider, and frontend should act accordingly
3. Authentication, Authorization - couple of possibilities at least

   - [WSSE](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) - stateless, token based
   - cookie based - You'll need to have custom authentication handlers and logout success handlers to send JSON responses
4. Use [verbatim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html) tags than customizing interpolation symbols in angular - it'll likely to break third party plugins or directives.

Two examples

1. https://github.com/thujeevan/sad - uses cookie based authentication
2. https://github.com/FlyersWeb/angular-symfony - uses WSSE based authentication

Hope, you'll catch things up